# Configure Snapper/snapshots on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, btrfs, snapshot

I am getting an error while trying to configure snapper on F23. My root partition is btrfs, and I have installed the snapper package. The error is occurring when I initially try to create the default root config.

When I run the cmd:

```
snapper -c root create-config /
```

terminal output is:

```
Creating config failed (creating btrfs snapshot failed)
```

snapper.log:

```
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) Snapper.cc(createConfig):288 - Snapper create-config
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) Snapper.cc(createConfig):289 - libsnapper version 0.2.8
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) Snapper.cc(createConfig):291 - config_name:root subvolume:/ fstype:btrfs template_name:default
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) Snapper.cc(getConfigs):247 - Snapper get-configs
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) Snapper.cc(getConfigs):248 - libsnapper version 0.2.8
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(reload):114 - loading file /etc/sysconfig/snapper
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(getValue):235 - key:SNAPPER_CONFIGS value:
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(reload):114 - loading file /etc/sysconfig/snapper
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(getValue):235 - key:SNAPPER_CONFIGS value:
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(save):139 - saving file /etc/sysconfig/snapper
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(reload):114 - loading file /etc/snapper/config-templates/default
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(save):139 - saving file /etc/snapper/configs/root
2015-11-26 01:55:45 ERR libsnapper(3335) Btrfs.cc(createConfig):112 - create subvolume failed, ioctl(BTRFS_IOC_SUBVOL_CREATE) failed, errno:17 (File exists)
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(reload):114 - loading file /etc/sysconfig/snapper
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(getValue):235 - key:SNAPPER_CONFIGS value:root
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) SystemCmd.cc(SystemCmd):46 - constructor SystemCmd:"/usr/bin/rm '/etc/snapper/configs/root'"
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) SystemCmd.cc(execute):82 - SystemCmd Executing:"/usr/bin/rm '/etc/snapper/configs/root'"
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) SystemCmd.cc(doExecute):267 - stopwatch 0.002974s for "/usr/bin/rm '/etc/snapper/configs/root'"
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) SystemCmd.cc(doExecute):287 - system() Returns:0
2015-11-26 01:55:45 MIL libsnapper(3335) AsciiFile.cc(save):139 - saving file /etc/sysconfig/snapper
```

The error appears to be,

```
create subvolume failed, ioctl(BTRFS_IOC_SUBVOL_CREATE) failed, errno:17 (File exists)
```

but Google has not been much help on this error.

Do I need to do or enable something in my btrfs root partition first?

Comment: I was able to create the initial root config (installed F23 today so maybe some fixes made it) but have problems with further steps: `semanage permissive -a snapperd_t` lets me now create snapshots via dnf but I am unable to diff them.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find this, but it appears there is a bug in SELinux which is causing this. Not actually a bug per se, but it has to do with snapperd not having *dac_override* capabilities by default. I contributed to the bug report that is open.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1282836